# How can I move image slowly?

Tags: java, image, swing, animation, java-2d

I want to move Images slowly.But drawImage() method only takes int values.Is there any method to move pictures slowly.I want to make ground move to the left a little bit slowly.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Board extends JPanel {

private Image ground;
private Image city;
private int x = 0;


public Board() {
    ground = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Resources\\ground2.png");
    city = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Resources\\background2.png");
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(ground, x--, 500, 600, 200, this);
    g.drawImage(ground, x + 600, 500, 600, 200, this);
    repaint();
    g.drawImage(city, 0, 0, 600, 500, this);

    if(x == -600){
        x = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can make ```Double x``` and then use ```Double.intValue()``` in the ```drawImage``` method. But I'm not sure it's the best thing to do since it will repaint the picture multiple times on the same coordinates which is pointless. When are you calling the paint method? Maybe you could limit the updates there.

Comment: Generally speaking the appropriate way would be to have a separate `Timer` thread responsible for calculating the movement and calling `paint` if necessary. Continually repainting is inefficient and likely to cause visual artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Swing Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for changing your `x` variable and repainting. Add next code to your `Board` constructor:

```
Timer t = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         x--;
         repaint();
    }
});
t.start();
```

Also do custom paintings in `paintComponent()` method instead of `paint()`:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(ground, x, 500, 600, 200, this);
    g.drawImage(ground, x + 600, 500, 600, 200, this);
    g.drawImage(city, 0, 0, 600, 500, this);

    if (x == -600) {
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

And don't call `repaint()` inside `paint()` or `paintComponent()` method.

Answer (score 1):

> `drawImage()` method only takes int values.Is there any method to move pictures slowly.

Sure.  Use an [`AffineTransform` translate instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getTranslateInstance%28double,%20double%29).  They can work with double values.  The resulting image drawing will then be 'dithered' along the edges to show what appears to be 'sub pixel accuracy' rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the rounding to int of your x isn't the problem. The real one is that you need to move using a time based animation instead of a frame based animation. You can use an approach based on float ( double is too much for your purpose ) or with integer doing some easy steps.
Add a member:

```
private long startTime = 0;
```

remove the int x as member.

And then change your code in your draw routine using something like:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    long delta;
    if ( startTime == 0 ) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        delta = 0;
    } else {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        delta = now - startTime;
    }
    //using startTime instead of lastTime increase very slow speed accuracy
    const long speed = 30; //pixel/sec
    //threshold with your image width
    int x = (int)((( speed * delta ) / 1000l)%600l);
    //

    //--- your draw code ---

    //
}
```

Et voila!

Comment: Instead of manipulate with `System.currentTimeMillis();` , OP need to use `Timer`.

Comment: Timer is a scheduler for threads. You don't need something like that in a draw routine. Some other piece of code in some way will call the repaint of the entire view and the background will react according to it. For me it can't be scheduled.